# ThrowMacValidationError on Iphone & Android

Tags: android, iphone, asp.net

I have a web application written in ASP.NET.
I have some wierd problems sometimes in which I get ThrowMacValidationError/Invalid viewstate.
I have noticed that these errors occur in android clients and/or iphone clients.
However, I've tested my site in both devices and did not have this problem.

What can cause this?

Thanks!

Update: It happens on IE9 too sometimes.
This seems to be very 1 out of many requests... I cant point my finger on this.

Comment: It seems that this is a server configuration issue: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2009/04/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-after-installing-net-3-5-sp1.aspx

Comment: @PeterKnego, I am using .NET v4... is it still might be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many conditions that may throw a ViewState Exception but I guess that this link [Does viewstate expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233828/does-viewstate-expire) may answer the most likely case, especial for mobile device.

Here is why mobile device are more exposed to this issue:

1. I visit **MyPage.aspx** with one PostBack link called **MyPostBackLink**.
2. Before clicking on that link I get a *SMS* or *any other distraction* that causes me to forget about the web page.
3. 20 minutes later (default Session expire time) I remember about that web page.
4. Open the Mobile browser and **MyPage.aspx** is still there and loaded.
5. Click on **MyPostBackLink** and I get a generic ViewState exception.

[Does viewstate expire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233828/does-viewstate-expire) also gives different ways of "fixing" this.